# Lorentz scalar of chiral fermions

Tags: gauge-theory, group-theory, fermions, chirality

In lectures on [Gauge Theory](http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/gaugetheory.html) by David Tong (sec. 5.6.1), the author suggests a Lorentz scalar $\epsilon^{\alpha\beta} \psi_{+\alpha}\psi_{+\beta}$ where $\psi_+$ is a right-handed fermion and $\alpha,\beta$ are spinor indices.

> We can take a pair of left- or right-handed fermions and form a Lorentz scalar $\epsilon^{\alpha\beta}\psi_{+\alpha}\psi_{+\beta}$ where, for once, we’ve explicitly written the $\alpha,\beta$, spinor indices. This means that it’s possible to contract the spinor indices such that each baryon above is left-handed.

I wonder how to derive it and I think we need a Dirac conjugate fermion $\bar{\psi}$ or $\bar{\psi}_-$ to form a Lorentz scalar quantity. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: $\epsilon_{\alpha\beta}$ is simply the invariant tensor of $SU(2)$

Comment: Write explicitly transformations for Weyl fermions and contract them using $\varepsilon$

Comment: You are right. This was a naive question...